# WPF Application doesn't fit into all the monitor screen

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF application that fits into my computer screen having screen resolution 1920 * 1080. But the same WPF application doesn't fit into my Microsoft Surface screen having same resolution 1920 * 1080. The exact issue is, it doesn't show the scroll bar in that little laptop. The issue is in the XAML for the page I am having trouble with and the window that hosts it. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

The code is something like this right now.

```
  <Page x:Class="form_Dock" Background="#FF19191E"  MouseEnter="Page_MouseEnter" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC.UI" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a scaling issue caused by WPF using device independent pixels to determine the size of the application. The Surface screen is pretty small, so there may be some scaling done in Windows to compensate, which is throwing the size of your window out.

You might be able to fix your problem by setting SnapsToDevicePixels on the window element to true:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, this explains device independent pixels quite well:

https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/02/19/759-device-independent-units-dips/

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I tried to use this in my code. Below is the piece of the code where I am using it.                                    
  <Page x:Class="form_Main" Background="#FF19191E"  MouseEnter="Page_MouseEnter" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">. Is this where I need to put the code in SnapsToDevicePixels="True"? This is in <Page> tag not in Windows. Does it matter? I tested in surface. it doesnt work.

Comment: You are supposed to set SnapToDevicePixels on the root element, which is normally a Window object. Pages need to be contained in another element to display, so putting SnapToDevicePixels there won't be right. Does your WPF project run in an application window or a browser? If you've given the Page a width that is wider than it's container then it would probably show scrollbars.

Comment: You mentioned Prism and Wpftoolkit above - are you using one of their controls?

Comment: My WPF project opens up in the same screen when we click on a button. We haven't used <Windows> in this page. We have used <Page>.

Comment: Could you update the question with the XAML for the page you're having trouble with and the window that hosts it? It might be easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok. Will do. Do you have any fix for this issue? The exact issue is, it crops some portion of the application in Microsoft Surface.

Comment: Another window will host the Page element - could you post the XAML for that too?